# Push notification using WiFi

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

I am working on an app which plays music and streams it over Wifi to other users who are connected to the same WiFi network using the aforementioned app. I was wondering if there is any way someone be notified to download the app and join the music stream. Maybe provide the play store link on the notification so that the app can be downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

User's device has to register Push notification servers before able to get any notification. So You cannot send them remote or local push notifications.To able to send  Push notification , your app has been already installed in their device.

As they are in same wifi network , if you have network admin credentials , you can redirect them into login page (simple button page maybe)  and show your advertisement. Or you can parse their http request and amend in proxy server.

https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-show-ads-to-the-people-in-my-WiFi